# Entity Framework 4 function import no rows returned error

Tags: entity-framework-4

In EF4 I am doing a function import of a stored procedure that returns a collection of string scalars.  However, sometimes the stored procedure may not return any values.  I do not own the stored procedure and cannot change it.  If the stored procedure returns no values, my code throws an exception "The data reader returned by the data store provider does not have enough columns for the query requested".  Is there any more graceful way of handling this situation than to attempt to catch the exception and assume that the no rows condition is what caused it?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround could be returning a dummy row if there are no matching records.